# Is it worth it to call R function within a julia loop?

Tags: r, julia

This question is probably very naive but is there an advantage in terms of performance to call R functions within Julia loop (with RCall module) rather than within R loop (since R loops are slow)? Of course numerous R Call from Julia do not seem very efficient but did anyone test it?

I expect some experts could point out the limits, and the pro/con of such approach. Thank you.

Comment: We don't have code so we can't tell you. We don't know if you've profiled your code to see where the bottlenecks are so we can't tell you. We don't know if you've done any tests to see what the Julia R call interface introduces in terms of object marshalling overhead. We don't know the sizes of the objects you'd be marshalling. We don't know if you're growing vectors, lists or data frames incrementally in said "loops". All this leads to  "unclear what you are asking" .

Comment: @hrbrmstr . I was just asking if anyone has experience in calling R function within Julia loop to know whether it is a good idea or not in general not for my specific case ! I expect some experts could point out the limits, and the pro/con of such approach

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr** It depends but probably not.

Basically "it depends". But if all you are doing in the loop is calling a piece of R code then probably not ... i.e. the overhead is going to be bigger than just doing it all in one language. If you can find C bindings into the underlying R package you want to use (they may or may not exist) then using ccall could be worth it.

Very rough benchmarks (take with handfuls of salt, extra run for compilation not shown).

```
f1(N) = begin
   R"x=0"
   for i in 1:N
       R"x = x + $i*1.4"
   end
   x = rcopy(R"x")
end


f2(N) = begin rcopy(R"""
   x = 0
   for (i in 1:$N) {
       x = x + i*1.4
   }
   x
   """)
 end

julia> @time f1(10000)
  0.706926 seconds (919.54 k allocations: 26.697 MiB, 1.80% gc time)
7.0007e7

julia> @time f2(10000)
  0.010227 seconds (129 allocations: 4.281 KiB)
7.0007e7
```

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed a good idea to directly call the C function from the R package.